# Favicon redirect in django 2.0

Tags: django, python-3.x, redirect, favicon

I'm trying to redirect the default browsers request of **/favicon.ico** to serve the picture from my static folder and I get a 404([server log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGkYO.png)).

### settings.py

```py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

### urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(
        'favicon.ico',
        RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('upload.ico'))
    ),
    path('', include('uploader.urls'))
]
```

My directory structure:

```
  ../  
  ├ imguploader/  
  |  ├  __init__.py  
  |  ├  settings.py
  |  ├  urls.py
  |  └  wsgi.py
  ├  static/  
  |  ├  admin/  
  |  └  upload.ico
  ├ manage.py
  |...
```

Comment: Have you run collectstatic?

Comment: Yes that's why the admin folder is in static/

Comment: File permissions on upload.ico?

Answer (score 4):

You can set STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py, works for me:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('favicon.ico', RedirectView.as_view(url=settings.STATIC_URL + 'favicon.ico')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```